# Exiting Loop using Enter(Return Key) C++

Tags: c++

First of all thanks for answering and helping out...
Now i was making a program to let the user enter any number... and then use the program to point out the total number of 4's in the the number entered and i have now encountered a problem..

This is my first post here so please excuse me if i make any mistakes..

**The Code**

```
int main()
{
    int T,i,j,l;
    char N,p[10];
    cin>>T;
    while(T--)   //The number of times a user can enter a new number
    {
        cout<<"\nEnter Numbers\n";
        l=0;i=0;
        do
        {
            N=getch();  //getch is used so that the enter key need not be pressed and the 
                        //number looks like a whole and also so the each number is 
                        //individually stored  
            p[i]=N;    //here the number entered is stored in p
            cout<<N;  //to display the number obviously
            l++;i++;
        }while(N!=' ');  //Now here between '' something has to be present so that the loop 
                         //terminates as soon as the enter key is pressed right now as soon 
                         //as the spacebar is hit the loop will terminate. 
        cout<<"\n";
        j=0;
        for(i=0;i<l;i++)  //using l so that the loop runs accordingly
        {
            if(p[i]=='4') 
            {
                j++;    //for couting the number of 4's
            }
            cout<<p[i]<<"\n";   //wont be needing in the final program but here cout is just
                               // to check the output
        }
        cout<<"\n THERE ARE "<<j<<" FOURS\n";
    }
}
```

Please not that i already have a solution for my program so please DO NOT  provide a different code using some different logic... i really need this very same program to work.i know that this program can be made to work using string length but here i want the loop to terminate after the enter key is pressed.

Comment: @DrZoo can u do this?

Comment: Why would you not want to ability to be shown different logic? Another way could be much more efficient and a method you'd want to replicate down the road

Comment: @JeffS thanks for responding .. i know another logic.. actually i was very keen to know if the enter thingy would work ..but seems difficult ... i am open to new ideas so yeah another logic yeah why not..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to see check if `N` is equal to `'\r'`. So your while loop looks like

```
    do
    {
        N=getch();  //getch is used so that the enter key need not be pressed and the 
                    //number looks like a whole and also so the each number is 
                    //individually stored  
        p[i]=N;    //here the number entered is stored in p
        cout<<N;  //to display the number obviously
        l++;i++;
    }while(N!='\r');
```

Answer (score 2):

Well if you want to stop getting input when the user presses enter instead of space you need to test against `'\r'`, `'\n'` or `'\r\n'` depending on what OS you are using.  That said you really should be using standard C++ if you are going to use C++.  You could easily make your code like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int loops;
    std::cout << "How many numbers to check: ";
    std::cin >> loops;
    std::cin.get(); // eat newline
    for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
    {
        std::string numbers;
        std::cout << "Enter numbers and press enter: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, numbers);
        auto numberOf4s = std::count(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), '4');
        std::cout << "Number of 4's entered: " << numberOf4s << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Example](https://ideone.com/wyTgl9)

Comment: thanks bro..Can u please tell me why u use 'std::' i have seen many people using it but i dont know its use..

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice